# Rule Table (With wild cards)

Tags: sql, sql-server, rule-engine

I have searched the web for something similar to my question, but have not found anything. I am looking for a way to apply "rules" with a SQL query.

```
My input data schema:
a: Int (NOT NULL)
b: Int (NOT NULL)
c: Int (NOT NULL)

The rule table schema:
a: Int (NULLABLE)
b: Int (NULLABLE)
c: Int (NULLABLE)
result: Int (NOT NULL)
```

There could be multiple rules which could "match" with the data. NULL represents a wildcard (could be any value). For example:

```
Input Data
a  |  b  |  c
1  |  2  |  3

Rules table:
a  |  b  |  c  |  result
1  |  2  | NULL|    99
1  | NULL| NULL|    101
1  |  2  |  3  |    203
```

When the rules are applied, it should match with the row which has the most matches (row 3 in this case).

I have come up with a query, which appears to be working, but it is not perfect. It can be slow if the "rules" table gets significant in size, and I'm worried there are edge cases I could be missing.

```
SELECT input.*, 
    COALESCE(rule.result, -1) as 'RuleResult'
FROM dbo.input input
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 result
    FROM dbo.RuleTable rt
        WHERE (input.a = rt.a OR rt.a IS NULL)
        AND (input.b = rt.b OR rt.b IS NULL)
        AND (input.c = rt.c OR rt.c IS NULL)
    ORDER BY rt.a DESC, rt.b DESC, rt.c DESC
) rule
```

The idea is: The outer apply will run the query for each row in the input. The ORDER BY clause will set the priority of the rules, and will have the columns with the least number of NULL values at the top. The top row then becomes the result. The ORDER BY clause needs to align with the business need. If there is one rule with an 'a' value, and another with a 'b' value, an input row could match with two rules which only have a single matching condition. Then one still needs to be chosen.

**My question:** Is this query optimal? Am I missing anything? Are there resources about this out there I have not found? Is there a better way of doing this?

**Update 1:** After reading replies and discussing this with other people, here are some additional thoughts (still need to test these out):

1. Can we reverse the join? Basically join the rule table to the data
2. Can we eliminate input data that we know no rules apply to? Is this possible with NULLS (wildcard) values, or would this help?

Note: I'm still working through the thought process on this, so I may not be super clear yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `ORDER BY` in the `OUTER APPLY` could use a small change

```
    ORDER BY (iif(rt.a is null,0,1)
             +iif(rt.b is null,0,1)
             +iif(rt.c is null,0,1)) desc, 
             rt.a desc, rt.b desc, rt.c desc
```

**Sample Data**

> ```
> create table input (a int, b int, c int);
> insert into input values
> (1,2,3),
> (1,2,null),
> (1,null,null), 
> (4,5,6);
>
> create table RuleTable (a int, b int, c int, result int);
> insert into RuleTable values 
> (1,2,null, 120),
> (1,null,null, 100),
> (1,2,3, 123), 
> (4,null,null, 400),
> (null,5,6, 056);
> ```

**Query**

> ```
> SELECT input.*
> , COALESCE(ruled.result, -1) as RuleResult
> FROM input input
> OUTER APPLY (
>     SELECT TOP 1 result
>     FROM RuleTable as rt
>         WHERE (input.a = rt.a OR rt.a IS NULL)
>           AND (input.b = rt.b OR rt.b IS NULL)
>           AND (input.c = rt.c OR rt.c IS NULL)
>     ORDER BY (iif(rt.a is null,0,1)
>              +iif(rt.b is null,0,1)
>              +iif(rt.c is null,0,1)) desc, 
>              rt.a desc, rt.b desc, rt.c desc
> ) ruled
> ORDER BY a desc, b desc, c desc;
> ```

**Result**

> | a | b | c | RuleResult |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 4 | 5 | 6 | 56 |
> | 1 | 2 | 3 | 123 |
> | 1 | 2 | *null* | 120 |
> | 1 | *null* | *null* | 100 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3df29310029947339a092adecdea83c1)*

Comment: This is an interesting thought. What is your reasoning for doing it this way?
I'm thinking of a potential issue where there are two rules which only have one value set (rule 1: a -> 1, rule 2: b -> 2) (assume these are the only rules). The input would match with both of them, and I don't think there would be a guarantee on the ordering. You have added the result value to the ordering, which I don't think fits my use case.

Comment: The result was added simply to include a tie breaker, just in case. F.e. if there's 2 rules with 2 matching. And this logic doesn't depend on the order of a, b, c.

Comment: I've change it. And the test has 2 more rules. The logic used in the question would get result 400 from it.